# How to display the validation error in blade using ajax?

Tags: ajax, laravel, validation

How to display the error message in blade using ajax? My code working well, the validation message appear in inspect element, but not in my blade form. I'm using Laravel 8.

Controller

```php
    public function store(StudentRequest $request)
    {
        $request->validate();
        $input = $request->all();

        Student::updateOrCreate(['id' => $request->id], $input);
        return response()->json(['success' => 'Added new student']);
    }
```

I'm using form request to handle the validation:

Request

```php
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name'  => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email',
        ];
    }
```

And this is my blade. I used `printErrorMsg()` to display all the validation error above the form, but it doesn't work and showed nothing.

Blade

```
    <form id="studentForm" name="studentForm" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
        {{ csrf_field() }}

        <div class="alert alert-danger print-error-msg" style="display:none">
            <ul></ul>
        </div>

        <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Enter Name" value="">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter Email" value="">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="saveBtn" value="create">Save changes</button>
        </div>

    </form>
    @endsection

    @push('scripts')
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });

        $('#createNewStudent').click(function() {
            $('#saveBtn').val("create-student");
            $('#id').val('');
            $('#studentForm').trigger("reset");
            $('#modelHeading').html("Create New Student");
            $('#ajaxModel').modal('show');
        });

        $('#studentForm').submit(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            let formData = new FormData(this);

            $.ajax({
                data: formData,
                url: "{{ route('students.store') }}",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: false,
                cache: false,
                processData: false,
                success: function(data) {
                    if($.isEmptyObject(data.error)){
                        alert(data.success);
                        $('#studentForm').trigger("reset");
                        $('#ajaxModel').modal('hide');
                        table.draw();
                    }else{
                        printErrorMsg(data.error);
                    }
                },
            });
        });

        function printErrorMsg (msg) {
            $(".print-error-msg").find("ul").html('');
            $(".print-error-msg").css('display','block');
            $.each( msg, function( key, value ) {
                $(".print-error-msg").find("ul").append('<li>'+value+'</li>');
            });
        }
    });
    </script>

    @endpush
```

Edited:

I solved this by linktoahref's answer and Sachin Kumar's comment. I remove `printErrorMsg()` function in my blade and change it to spans element for each field with id and using responseText to return the js strings. So, here's the edited code:

Blade:

```
<div class="form-group">
 <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
 <div class="col-sm-12">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" name="email"/>
  <small id="email_error" class="form-text text-danger"></small>
 </div>
</div>

$('#studentForm').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#name_error').text('');
    $('#email_error').text('');
    let formData = new FormData(this);
    $.ajax({
        data: formData,
        url: "{{ route('students.store') }}",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(data) {
            if (data.status == true) {
                alert('Success!');
                $('#studentForm').trigger("reset");
                $('#ajaxModel').modal('hide');
                table.draw();
            }
        },
        error: function(reject) {
            var response = $.parseJSON(reject.responseText);
            $.each(response.errors, function(key, val) {
                $("#" + key + "_error").text(val[0]);
            })
        }
    });
});
```

Thank you

Comment: you should check the HTTP status code. If it is 422 then each key of the error represents the element name. Then according to the logic. You can create a span element with id like `<span id="name-error">The validation error message for name</span>` and insertAfter element.

Comment: Hi, the output which you have shown is of `data` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extending Sachin Kumar's comment, the validation errors returned from Laravel would have an http response code
of 422 and would be available in the [`error`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) callback of AJAX.

So you may add additional spans in your html to accommodate the errors and hide it initially and display it on validation errors.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <input type="text" 
            class="form-control"
            id="name"
            name="name"
            placeholder="Enter Name" value="">
        <span class="error text-danger d-none"></span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <input type="text" 
            class="form-control"
            id="email"
            name="email"
            placeholder="Enter Email" value="">
        <span class="error text-danger d-none"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

And process the validation errors in the error callback as follows:

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    error: function (err) {
        $.each(err.responseJSON.errors, function (key, value) {
            $("#" + key).next().html(value[0]);
            $("#" + key).next().removeClass('d-none');
        });
    },
    ...
});
```

Comment: hi, sorry for late response. I already try it, and I got this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'errors' of undefined.

Comment: Maybe try debugging what's in the `err` variable `console.log(err);` would help

Comment: @linktoahref for this method, how do I add the d-none class back once the validation passed? Tried many method but didn't work out.

Comment: @cleopatez Once the validation is passed, you may add the `d-none` class using the `success` callback of the ajax function.